# Delphi XE7. How to calculate different time zones?

Tags: delphi, timezone, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I know this question has been asked hundred times before but I am struggling to find a solution for Delphi Firemonkey XE7.

I can use `Winapi.Windows` (as described in [Convert TDateTime to Another Time Zone Regardless of Local Time Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690739/convert-tdatetime-to-another-time-zone-regardless-of-local-time-zone)) but what is the solution for Firemonkey?

Comment: For what OS? This is going to be an OS-dependent answer, and you've already got an answer for Windows. There are still parts of code that have to be written for different platforms, which is why they provide `{$IFDEF MACOS}` and other compiler defines to differentiate.

Comment: https://github.com/pavkam/tzdb